# Whoa, A Bad Relationship

Tags: tomodachi-life

So the female Mii told me her relationship with a male and I said yes. She only rejected two, and they got along with each other. But a few days later she showed "Slightly Unhappy" and now I am worried about their relationship.

How do I make a female get along with her sweetheart again?

Answer (score 1):

Send them on a trip! Give one of them a travel ticket - if they don't take their significant other, reset and give it to the other one, and hopefully they'll be more cooperative. When they go on a trip, it will generally (maybe always?) raise each of their happiness in the relationship.